# Custom Keyboard: handling inputType change

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I am running into an issue that I can't figure out. I wrote a simple custom IME keyboard based on [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) sample.

It basically has two custom keyboards, one for letters and one for numbers. They use different layouts.

However, when I add two `EditText` controls one for text and one for numbers, the keyboard does not refresh to the type it belongs. What I mean is that if I select the `EditText` with `inputType="text"` first, the QWERTY keyboard layout comes up. But then when I select the second `EditText` with `inputType="number"` the QWERTY keyboard shows up again. However it is supposed to load a different layout for numbers that is wired into the code.

In other words, here's the test activity layout:

[image]

Now if I select the "Text" field, the QWERTY keyboard comes up as below:

[image]

However, if I select the "Number" filed, the QWERTY keyboard still shows up which is wrong.

[image]

The expected behavior would be this keyboard to show up.

[image]

Here's the code for the CustomIME and I tried to use `postInvalidate()` on the view, pre-load all layouts during `onInitializeInterface()` but nothing worked. It never switches to the number's layout properly

```
public class CustomIME extends InputMethodService
        implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    public static final String CUSTOM_IME = "CUSTOM_IME";
    private KeyboardView mKeyboardView;
    private Keyboard mKeyboardCurrent;
    private KeyboardType mKeyboardTypeCurrent = KeyboardType.QWERTY_LETTERS;
    private boolean mCAPs = false;


    enum KeyboardType {
        QWERTY_LETTERS,
        NUMBERS
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        loadCurrentKeyboard();
        mKeyboardView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_ime_keyboard, null);
        mKeyboardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_gradient);
        mKeyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);

        if (mKeyboardCurrent != null) {
            mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(mKeyboardCurrent);
        }

        return mKeyboardView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializeInterface() {
        // tried loading everything here but did not make a difference
    }

    private void loadCurrentKeyboard() {
        if (mKeyboardTypeCurrent == KeyboardType.QWERTY_LETTERS) {
            mKeyboardCurrent = new Keyboard(getApplicationContext(), R.xml.custom_ime_qwerty);
        } else if (mKeyboardTypeCurrent == KeyboardType.NUMBERS) {
            mKeyboardCurrent = new Keyboard(getApplicationContext(), R.xml.custom_ime_number);
        } else {
            Log.e(CUSTOM_IME, "Invalid keyboard type");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartInput(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
        super.onStartInput(attribute, restarting);
        switch (attribute.inputType & InputType.TYPE_MASK_CLASS) {
            case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER:
                boolean signed = (attribute.inputType & InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED) != 0;
                boolean decimal = (attribute.inputType & InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL) != 0;

                // set default
                mKeyboardTypeCurrent = KeyboardType.QWERTY_LETTERS;
                if (!signed && !decimal) {
                    mKeyboardTypeCurrent = KeyboardType.NUMBERS;
                }
                break;
            case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT:
            default:
                mKeyboardTypeCurrent = KeyboardType.QWERTY_LETTERS;
        }

        // This did not make a difference
        if (mKeyboardView != null) {
            mKeyboardView.postInvalidate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
        InputConnection inputConnection = getCurrentInputConnection();
        switch (primaryCode) {
            default:
                char asciiCode = (char) primaryCode;
                if (Character.isLetter(asciiCode) && mCAPs) {
                    asciiCode = Character.toUpperCase(asciiCode);
                }
                inputConnection.commitText(String.valueOf(asciiCode), 1);
        }
    }
}
```

And the layouts:

custom_ime_keyboard.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/custom_ime_keyboard_id1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/custom_ime_preview" />
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:hint="Text"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:hint="Number"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Finally the keyboard layouts (**custom_ime_qwerty.xml**, and **custom_ime_number.xml**).

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyHeight="64dp"
    android:keyWidth="9%p">
    <!--1st row-->
    <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="top">
        <Key
            android:codes="113"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:keyLabel="q" />
        <Key
            android:codes="119"
            android:keyLabel="w" />
        <Key
            android:codes="101"
            android:keyLabel="e" />
        <Key
            android:codes="114"
            android:keyLabel="r" />
        etc...


<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keyHeight="64dp"
    android:keyWidth="20%p"
    android:label="number"
    android:verticalGap="0px">
    <!--1st row-->
    <Row android:rowEdgeFlags="top">
        <Key
            android:codes="49"
            android:keyEdgeFlags="left"
            android:keyLabel="1" />
        <Key
            android:codes="50"
            android:keyLabel="2" />
        <Key
            android:codes="51"
            android:keyLabel="3" />
```

Comment: I believe that azizbekian is correct. You will need to change your code to add `onStartInputView()`. It will look something like this.

    @Override
    public void onStartInputView(EditorInfo info, boolean restarting) {
 super.onStartInputView(attribute, restarting);
 loadCurrentKeyboard();
        kv.setKeyboard(mKeyboardCurrent);
    }

Comment: Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Cheticamp/597d6442218af34a3bfae773c286ef4e) with working code for simple numeric and text keyboards..

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think [`onStartInputView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onStartInputView(android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo,%20boolean)) is the callback you need to obtain:

> Called when the input view is being shown and input has started on a new editor. This will always be called after **onStartInput(EditorInfo, boolean)**, allowing you to do your general setup there and just view-specific setup here. You are guaranteed that **onCreateInputView()** will have been called some time before this function is called.

So, you get to know what exact input type to show in [`onStartInput()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onStartInput(android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo,%20boolean)), but the actual place to perform switching to this new keyboard type should be [`onStartInputView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/InputMethodService.html#onStartInputView(android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo,%20boolean)).

See how the sample [`SoftKeyboard`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/src/com/example/android/softkeyboard/SoftKeyboard.java#259) application handles that functionality.

```
@Override public void onStartInput(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
    super.onStartInput(attribute, restarting);

    ...

    // We are now going to initialize our state based on the type of
    // text being edited.
    switch (attribute.inputType & InputType.TYPE_MASK_CLASS) {
        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER:
        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME:
            mCurKeyboard = mSymbolsKeyboard;
            break;

        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE:
            mCurKeyboard = mSymbolsKeyboard;
            break;

        case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT:
            mCurKeyboard = mQwertyKeyboard;
            ...
            break;

        default:
            // For all unknown input types, default to the alphabetic
            // keyboard with no special features.
            mCurKeyboard = mQwertyKeyboard;
    }

}

@Override public void onStartInputView(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
    super.onStartInputView(attribute, restarting);
    // Apply the selected keyboard to the input view.
    setLatinKeyboard(mCurKeyboard);
    ...
}

private void setLatinKeyboard(LatinKeyboard nextKeyboard) {
    final boolean shouldSupportLanguageSwitchKey =
            mInputMethodManager.shouldOfferSwitchingToNextInputMethod(getToken());
    nextKeyboard.setLanguageSwitchKeyVisibility(shouldSupportLanguageSwitchKey);
    mInputView.setKeyboard(nextKeyboard);
}
```

Comment: As a note, `InputType.TYPE_MASK_CLASS` is just used for the overall type. You wouldn't use this mask if you needed a more specific type like `InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PHONETIC`. There is also a `TYPE_MASK_VARIATION`.